# Alternative to Executing Python in CMD?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, cmd, command-prompt

I have download Python v2 and Sublime Text 2. When I execute code with python the code window console thing is in a CMD window. I didn't mind this until now. I am working on a cipher code type thing and the CMD window isn't reacting well to me copying and pasting. I want to know if there is a program or something that will allow me to paste large chunks of text without really messing up the text? The average text pasting size is probably this:

```
?etoiacldrubmwptoagetoiacldrubmwptoanetoiacldrubmwptoaietoiacldrubmwptoaoetoiacl
drubmwptoadetoiacldrubmwptoa etoiacldrubmwptoauetoiacldrubmwptoaoetoiacldrubmwpt
oayetoiacldrubmwptoa etoiacldrubmwptoaeetoiacldrubmwptoaretoiacldrubmwptoaaetoia
cldrubmwptoa etoiacldrubmwptoawetoiacldrubmwptoaoetoiacldrubmwptoahetoiacldrubmw
ptoa etoiacldrubmwptoa,etoiacldrubmwptoawetoiacldrubmwptoaoetoiacldrubmwptoaleto
iacldrubmwptoaletoiacldrubmwptoaeetoiacldrubmwptoah
```

I would be pasting large amounts of text probably this big. But the default CMD window is not very useful for this. Any suggestions for alternatives to execute the command with better copy/paste abilities?

Comment: With quick edit mode enabled you can paste from the clipboard using the right mouse button. For pasting multi-line text, try  `s = r'''` [paste] `'''`. Also, it's a console window, not a CMD window. The latter misleadingly implies the window is created by cmd.exe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the IDLE console?

From my experience it is easy to copy and paste out of it.
Also, have you thought about outputting the stdout to a file? Then you will be able to copy or paste very very easily.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try Ipython notebook which is very convenient for interactive work like Copy-paste-run

Answer (score 0):

use `pycharm` has built in console or `python idle` provides you pure python enviornment

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use https://hyper.is/ [image]

the most beautiful terminal out there for windows . this is still on beta so you might find bugs here and there but its in active development